# Graphql: how to query using prefix string

Tags: javascript, graphql

I have the following query in GraphQL:

```
{
  allBibliografia(nome: "Bibliografia 1") {
    id
    nome
  }
}
```

which works. But I need to query my backend using a prefix string, as the user is typing. For example: if I type "Bibliografia 1" as above, my query returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "allBibliografia": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "nome": "Bibliografia 1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but if I input just "Bibliografia" or "Bibliografia*", I get this

```
{
  "data": {
    "allBibliografia": []
  }
}
```

I was hoping that "Bibliografia*" would work just like a wildcard for SQL, but it didn't. Does anybody knows how to achieve that?

Comment: This looks like a Graphcool-specific question. If so, you should indicate that in your question and tag it appropriately :)

Comment: Not really. We are using graphene for python. But you Just gave me am Idea. Unfortunatly I'll have to test It tomorrow.

Comment: can you try for like query concept in SQL

Comment: I don't understand @SVP Can you give me more details or provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Vini.g.fer  I meant to say some like query functionality to implement in your ORM tool like sequelize